# Where does my old laptop store my lock screen picture?

Tags: windows-10, lock-screen

My old laptop had a favorite family photograph as the lock screen image.  The laptop has been superseded by a newer model but I can't find the original image anywhere.  I've fired up my old laptop and the image is still the lock screen image, but I can't figure out where it's stored or if I can get it and copy it out. The machine is a Windows 10 Pro, 21H1.